# Delete a single db row after clicking delete button

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I have this query, where I want to delete a single row from **DB** when clicking on **delete** button. Right now, it's deleting the **whole DB row**. but I want to delete a single row by **ID**.

**Here's the** `code`

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'conference_register');
function conference_register(){
      add_options_page('Register Conference', 'Conference Registration',  'manage_options', 'conference-registration', 'display_conference');
}

function display_conference(){
    echo "<form method='post'>";
    echo "<div class='wrap'>";
    echo "<h2>Conference Registration User Details</h2>";
    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `id`,`email`,`details` FROM `conference_register`"); ?>
    <table class="wp-list-table widefat fixed striped pages">
      <thead>
          <tr>
            <th id="posts" class="manage-column column-posts num">ID</th>
            <th id="email" class="manage-column column-email">Email</th>      
            <th id="description" class="manage-column column-description">Details</th>
            <th id="posts" class="manage-column column-posts num">Delete</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody id="the-list">
   <?php foreach($results as $value){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td class='posts column-posts'>".$value->id."</td>";
        echo "<td class='email column-email'>".$value->email."</td>";
        echo "<td class='description column-description'><div id='col-container'>".$value->details."</div></td>";
        echo "<td class='posts column-posts'><input type='submit' name='delete_registration' value='delete'/></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
         if(isset($_POST['delete_registration'])){
            $wpdb->delete( 'conference_register', array( 'id' => $value->id ) );
        }

    }
    echo "</tbody></table></div></form>";
}
```

The `code` for clicking action is set like this in above code:

```
 if(isset($_POST['delete_registration'])){
    $wpdb->delete( 'conference_register', array( 'id' => $value->id ) );
}
```

Am I missing anything here? 
Any help will be appreciated.

**P.S.** I want to delete a row without using **jQuery**.

Comment: When you said the whole DB row, did you mean the whole table is deleted?

Comment: Yes, the whole table is deleted right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as you are deleting the row if `delete_registration` is set. You need to set/check it for each row and delete that particular row.

```
<?php foreach($results as $value){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class='posts column-posts'>".$value->id."</td>";
    echo "<td class='email column-email'>".$value->email."</td>";
    echo "<td class='description column-description'><div id='col-container'>".$value->details."</div></td>";
    $delRow = "delete_registration_{$value->id}";
    echo "<td class='posts column-posts'><input type='submit' name= $delRow value='delete'/></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
     if(isset($_POST[$delRow])){
        $wpdb->delete( 'conference_register', array( 'id' => $value->id ) );
    }

}
```

Comment: wait I'll give it a try.

Comment: nothing is happening now. The page just gets reloaded but a row not deleted.

Comment: are you having a delete button for each row ? Also check the updated answer.

Comment: Yes.. you can see the screenshot here
http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/639957/a319cd92005c25ef526045aa366d1adf

Comment: Yes, so the updated answer must work here. make sure you get `$value->id` in the `name` of the `delete` button input

Comment: When I click a delete button, the page refresh and no changes. **But ** if i reload the page again, the row is deleted. Your query helpful but do you have any idea about this ? why it's not deleting after a single button click?

Comment: does the page gets loaded after the button click ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91578/discussion-between-jitendra-purohit-and-prabin-parajuli).

Comment: yes the page gets loaded but shows not changes, but if I refresh the page only then shows the change.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the id or the database query syntax is not okay

Comment: Query syntax is fine, just cannot delete the single row.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 echo "<td class='posts column-posts'><input type='submit' name= 'delete_registration_{$value->id}' value='delete'/></td>";
 echo "</tr>";
  if(isset($_POST[delete_registration_{$value->id}])){
    $wpdb->delete( 'conference_register', array( 'id' => $value->id ) );
 }
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

How I do this is in each row I have a `hidden input` field and have default value = "x". When user changes any field I use javascript to change the value to "e" and if user clicks "delete" I change the value to "d" and submit the form.

On Submit I use a `switch` . Loop through all records, if e - edit, d-delete.